# Codeigniter: how to pass placeholder random-key in a language file

Tags: php, codeigniter, md5, placeholder

I need to pass the variable $key_breaf = md5 (uniqid ()); 
 to the language file to get a url like this: 
mysite.com/it/logo/2157d31f74c238950686a5ed9ff4b654/
 
But I get this error: Error 400

Working with the Internationalization (i18n) library
 
Where am I wrong?
Thanks in advance
**This is my controller:** (logo.php)

```
function index() {
    $this->load->helper('language');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->lang->load('general');


    $key_breaf = md5(uniqid());

    $lang = "it";

    // Load the file-and message language
    $this->lang->load('general', $lang);
    // load the key of the language and the %s placeholder variable $ key_breaf
    $url = sprintf($this->lang->line('link.logo.logo'), $key_breaf);
}
```

**This is my language file:** (general_lang.php)

```
$lang['link.logo.logo'] = "it/logo/%s";
```

Comment: I tested your code and it is working fine. If I **`print_r()`** your **`$url`** , I get this, **`it/logo/e6e482412ace6f3bef252a7357eb4e22`**. I think you are missing something in the question.